# script doesn't see arg in '$ ssh bash script arg'

Tags: bash, ssh

I'd like to see both commands print `hello`

```
$ bash -l -c "/bin/echo hello"
hello
$ ssh example_host bash -l -c /bin/echo hello

$
```

How can `hello` be passed as a parameter in the `ssh` command?

The `bash -l -c` is needed, so login shell startup scripts are executed.

Getting `ssh` to start a login shell would solve the problem too.

Comment: `ssh example_host 'bash -l -c "/bin/echo hello"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass extra args after `-c`, they're put into the argv of the shell while that command is executing. You can see that like so:

```
bash -l -c '/bin/echo "$0" "$@"' hello world
```

...so, those arguments aren't put on the command line of *echo* (unless you go out of your way to make it so), but instead are put on the command line *of the shell* which you're telling to run echo *with no arguments*.

That is to say: When you run

```
bash -l -c /bin/echo hello
```

...that's the equivalent of this:

```
(exec -a hello bash -c /bin/echo)
```

...which puts `hello` into `$0` of a bash which runs only `/bin/echo`. Since running `/bin/echo` doesn't look at `$0`, of course it's not going to print `hello`.

---

Now, because executing things via ssh means you're going through two steps of shell expansion, it adds some extra complexity. Fortunately, you can have the shell handle that for you automatically, like so:

```
printf -v cmd_str '%q ' bash -l -c '/bin/echo "$0" "$@"' hello world
ssh remote_host "$cmd_str"
```

This tells bash (`printf %q` is a bash extension, not available in POSIX printf) to quote your command such that it expands to itself when processed by a shell, then feeds the result into `ssh`.

---

All that said -- treating `$0` as a regular parameter is bad practice, and generally shouldn't be done absent a specific and compelling reason. The Right Thing is more like the following:

```
printf -v cmd '%q ' /bin/echo hello world  # your command
printf -v cmd '%q ' bash -l -c "$cmd"      # your command, in a login shell
ssh remotehost "$cmd"                      # your command, in a login shell, in ssh
```

Comment: still no joy when executing it via ssh:
    $ ssh example_host bash -l -c '/bin/echo "$0" "$@"' hello world

just returns newline only

Comment: @JoeDoyle, see the extension to the answer telling you how to use `printf %q` to prepare content for an `eval` pass (as performed by ssh, or sh -c, or in similar scenarios).

Comment: works great. hope it's easy to get to the same thing to work in a Python subprocess.Popen() call

Comment: The Python 2 equivalent to bash's `printf %q` is `pipes.quote()`; in Python 3, that's `shlex.quote()`.